# Saving Picture into Gallery from app

Tags: java, android, button

I have only began to code in java and am making an android application that takes a photo and saves the image to my gallery folder. My app takes the photo but for one reason or another it won't save the image.

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
public void onClickbtnCamera(View v){


        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }     




  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date(0));
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;

    }

  static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

  private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
      Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
      if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
          // Create the File where the photo should go
          File photoFile = null;
          try {
              photoFile = createImageFile();
          } catch (IOException ex) {
              // Error occurred while creating the File

          }
          // Continue only if the File was successfully created
          if (photoFile != null) {
              takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                      Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
              startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
          }
      }
  }
  private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "it won't save the image" means. I also recommend removing the `:` from the file path, as that might be a reserved character. Also, do not hardcode paths, as your hardcoded directory is wrong on hundreds of millions of Android devices.

Comment: It takes the photo no bother, but when I go to the location where it should have been saved it isn't there. Any ideas @CommonsWare

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "when I go to the location where it should have been saved" means. *How* do you "go to the location", and where do you think this "location" is? Are you using DDMS? Are you using a desktop OS file browser, with the device connected via USB cable? Are you using **`adb shell`** and checking directory listings on the command line? Are you using an on-device file browser? Are you doing something else?

Comment: I have the application installed on my phone. I open the application, click a button it opens the camera I take the photo. I then exit the application go into my gallery on my phone and then into my camera album where I believe the image should have saved into however there is no sign of it.

Comment: I suggested that you use `MediaScannerConnection`; you went a different route. I suggest that you **look for the file**, such as using some of the techniques I outlined in my previous comment, to determine whether the issue is that the actual image is not being saved in the file (suggesting a problem in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, like the colon, or a bug in your camera app), whether the image is just not being picked up by the camera album app, etc.